# How to display JSON object with Handlebars template

Tags: node.js, arrays, json, handlebars.js

I am trying to create a react-like component with Handlebars. In this project, I have a set of project cards that are inside a carousel. The cards consist of a photo, project name, project description, and project link. The information is being pulled from an API that I create with the JSON data looking something like this

```
[
  {
    _id: '627b281c0ee7f8ee7eb08703',
    name: 'Pamela',
    about: "Pamela's portfolio page",
    github: "pam's portfolio",
    website: 'https://github.com/AlexAntoine/Devcamper-api/blob/main/models/Bootcamp.js',
    tools: [ 'node js', 'Express', 'heroku', 'mongoDB', 'mongoose' ],
    content: [],
    __v: 0
  },
  {
    _id: '627b284f0ee7f8ee7eb08706',
    name: 'Mike',
    about: "Mike's portfolio page",
    github: "mike's portfolio",
    website: 'https://github.com/AlexAntoine/Devcamper-api/blob/main/models/Bootcamp.js',
    tools: [ 'node js', 'Express', 'heroku', 'mongoDB', 'mongoose', 'React' ],
    content: [],
    __v: 0
  },
  {
    _id: '627b28b00ee7f8ee7eb08709',
    name: 'Alex',
    about: "Alex's portfolio page",
    github: "alex's portfolio",
    website: 'https://github.com/AlexAntoine/Devcamper-api/blob/main/models/Bootcamp.js',
    tools: [
      'node js',
      'Express',
      'heroku',
      'mongoDB',
      'mongoose',
      'Angular'
    ],
    content: [],
    __v: 0
  }
]
```

My goal is to have a new card created with the information from each object. For example, the first card would be populated with "Pamela", "Pamela's portfolio page", and "https://github.com/AlexAntoine/Devcamper-api/blob/main/models/Bootcamp.js " The starting HBS code I have for this is

```
{{#each this}}
{{>header}}

<section class="s1">
    <div class="main-container">
        <div class="greeting-wrapper">  
            <h1>Hello I'm Don-Alex 2</h1>
        </div>

        <div class="intro-wrapper" >
            <div class="nav-wrapper">
                <div class="dots-wrapper"> 
                    <div id="dot-1" class="browser-dots"></div>
                    <div id="dot-2" class="browser-dots"></div>
                    <div id="dot-3" class="browser-dots"></div>
                </div>
                <ul id="navigation"> 
                    <li><a href="#one">Contact</a></li>
                </ul>
                
            </div>

            <div class="left-column">
                <img id="profile-pic" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1524502397800-2eeaad7c3fe5?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=634&q=80" alt="Profile Picture">
                <h5 >Personalize Theme</h5>

                <div id="theme-options-wrapper">

                    <div data-mode="light" class="theme-dot" id="light-mode"></div>
                    <div data-mode="blue" class="theme-dot" id="blue-mode"></div>
                    <div data-mode="green" class="theme-dot" id="green-mode"></div>
                    <div data-mode="purple" class="theme-dot" id="purple-mode"></div>
                </div>

                <p id="setting-note">*Theme options will be saved for<br>your next visit</p>
            </div>

            <div class="right-column">
                <div id="preview-shadow">
                    <div id="preview">
                        <div id="corner-tl" class="corner"></div>
                        <div id="corner-tr" class="corner"></div>
                        
                        <h3>What I Do </h3>
                        <p>Aspring software developer that enjoys building new things</p>

                        <div id="corner-br" class="corner"></div>
                        <div id="corner-bl" class="corner"></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>

<section class="s2">
    <div class="main-container">

        <div class="about-wrapper">
            <div class="about-me">
                <h4>More about me</h4>

                <p>Love watching anime and taking naps. </p>

                <hr>

                <h4>Top Expertise</h4>

                <p>What i'm good at <a href="resume.pdf" target="_blank">Download Resume</a> </p>

                <div id="skills">
                    <ul>
                        <li>HTML</li>
                        <li>CSS</li>
                        <li>Javascript</li>
                        <li>React</li>
                        <li>Bootstrap</li>
                    </ul>

                    <ul>
                    <li>Node.js</li>
                    <li>Mongoose</li>
                    <li>Express</li>
                    <li>MongoDB</li>
                    <li>Heroku</li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="social-links">
                <img id="social-img" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1618401471353-b98afee0b2eb?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1488&q=80" alt="Github">
                <h3>Find my latest projects on Github</h3>

                <a href="https://github.com/AlexAntoine" target="_blank">Github</a>
                <br>
            </div>
        </div>
        
    </div>
</section>

<section class="s1">
    <div class="main-container s1-container">
        <h3>Some of My Past Projects</h3>
 
        <div class="post-wrapper">
            <div id="carouselExampleInterval" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel" data-pause="hover">
                <div class="carousel-inner">
                    

                    <!--Add loop here. Figure out how that is going to work out.  -->
                    
                    <div class="carousel-item active container-fluid temp-container" data-interval="3000">
                         
                        <div class="post">
                           
                            <div class="card-container">
                                
                                <img class="thumbnail" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1514474959185-1472d4c4e0d4?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1674&q=80" alt="">
                                
                                  
                                    <div class="post-preview">
                                       
                                        <h6 class="post-title">{{this.name}}</h6>
                                        <p class="post-intro">{{this.about}}</p>
                                        <a href="/post/daily-journal">1</a>
                                       
                                    </div>
                                      
                                    
                                
                               
                            </div>
                            
                        </div>
                        
                        
                    </div>
                     
                </div>
                

                
                <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExampleInterval" role="button" data-slide="prev">
                    <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                    <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
                </a>
                <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExampleInterval" role="button" data-slide="next">
                    <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                    <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
                </a>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
</section>

<section class="s2" id="one">
    <div class="main-container">
        <h3>Get In Touch</h3>
        <form action="/"  id="contact-form">
            <label for="">Name</label>
            <input type="text" class="input-field" name="name">

            <label>Subject</label>
            <input type="text" name="subject" class="input-field">

            <label>Email</label>
            <input type="text" name="email" class="input-field">

            <label>Message</label>
            <textarea class="input-field" name="message"></textarea>

            {{!-- <input type="submit" name="submit-btn" value="send" id="submit-btn"> --}}
            <input type="submit" value="send" id="submit-btn">
        </form>
        
    </div>
</section>

{{>footer}}
{{/each}}
```

The server-side code that sends the data is written like this

```
app.get('/home2', async(req, res)=>{
    const {data:{result}}=  await axios.get(`https://antoine-portfolio-api.herokuapp.com/api/v1/projects`);

    const projects=  result.map((projects)=>{
        // console.log('line 62: ', project);
        return projects;
    });

    res.render('home2',{
        // title:'Alex home',
        name: projects,
        about: projects
    })

   

    
})
```

I cannot get the program to display the project name and the description for all three of the projects listed. Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: To start, I think you need to clean-up the object you are passing to `res.render`. Why is a reference to `projects` being assigned to both `name` and `about`? It looks like it would make more sense to assign it to a `projects` key and include an `{{#each projects}}` in your template.

Comment: I see where you are coming from and I tried it out. It worked for the first object but not for the rest. I was hoping I could do this without having to use React but that's proven difficult. Thank you for your input.

Comment: `#each` will loop over an array of objects. It's not clear what is the shape of the data you are passing to `res.render`.

Comment: the data is presented as an array of objects. "result" is the object.

Comment: `#each` should be sufficient for your purpose. See: https://jsfiddle.net/76484/zdykxma4/